# Creating charts with customized looks in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to add some nice looking charts to a Crystal Report.  I've gotten all the info on the report, sorted the way it should be, but can't get the format looking the way I want through the UI.  Here's what I need to do:

1. Rotate Y-Axis label vertically 45 degrees.  I can rotate it vertically 90 degrees, but I can only position it inside the chart.
2. Display group labels at the top of the chart.
3. Place a vertical line between each group.

**Current Report**
[image: Current Report]

**Desired Output**
[image: Desired Format]

Is this type of chart something that can be done programatically or through a 3rd party plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box.  In my case the reports were created by a ASP .NET web application, so charts for the reports could be pre-generated as image using external software.

Crystal Reports supports a limited set of charts and graphs with presets, so if none of these meet your needs it may not be the right solution.